# munin-node plugins : VCHI initialization failed

Tags: raspbian, sensor

I'm creating a munin plugin to fetch temp values from my Pi's.

When running the script, as root, everything is fine:

```
pi /etc/munin/plugins # ./temp 
temp.value 47.1
```

But when running it directly from Munin, it gives an error:

```
pi /etc/munin/plugins # telnet localhost 4949
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
# munin node at pi.yeri.be
fetch temp
temp.value VCHI initialization failed
```

Some users suggested to add the user (*munin* in my case) that would need access to */opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp* to the *plugdev* or *video* group. I've tried both and neither worked.

I don't want to run a cron from root that writes the value to a file and have munin cat that file. Is there a way to give Munin access to that command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use "user" in the Munin config:

[temp]
user root

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, my solution is adding my user to video group, and it worked like a charm.

```
sudo usermod -a -G video myuser
```

and a reboot afterward (the new groups will only be recognize after reboot).

Comment: had the same problem, simonsays is correct, it worked for me

Comment: @rdpayne Please don't post comments as answers they only serve to increase the noise level (I have converted your answer to a comment). Also instead of adding comments to say it worked vote up the answer and possibly the question which solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`vcgencmd` does not require root access to run (I could run it just fine from my non-root account) and `ls` command confirms this:

```
$ vcgencmd measure_temp
temp=58.4'C
$ ls -al /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15054 May 17 02:29 /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd
$
```

also you may read directly the `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` to get the temperature, it's available to read for everyone:

```
$ ls -al /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp 
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 18 22:15 /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
$
```

Comment: Yes, I can also run it from another user. But Munin, either the process or the user does not have access, as seen from my telnet command.

Comment: permissions `0444` mean EVERYBODY has access, your problem lies somewhere else. try to recreate the `temp.value VCHI initialization failed` situation manually, log as Munin or strip your permissions to its level and then you'll see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

login to root, and:

echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="vchiq", GROUP="video", MODE="0660"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/99-input.rules

check the file name "99-input.rules" is the same on your pi

Comment: Try to change the filename to `10-local-rpi.rules` instead of `99-input.rules`. I was confused with the problem, tried the variant proposed because I have a file `99-realsense-libusb.rules` which works OK, but `99-input.rules` should not work just because of a clue related to a numbers similarity.